# How many objects are eligible for garbage collector in this example?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How many objects are eligible to be deallocated by garbage collector at the given point **X**?

I'm somewhat confused with static and how it actually works with garbage collector. Could you explain me?

```
public class Star {
    static String nearbyPlanet = new String();
    String nome = new String();

    static void makeStar(String planet) {
        Star s = new Star();
        s.nearbyPlanet = planet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Star.makeStar("Mars");
        Star.makeStar("Venus"); /* X -- HERE!! -- */
        Star.makeStar("Krypton");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `makeStar` supposed to do? I at least expected it to `return s;`

Answer (score 0):

2 Stars are deallocatable plus 2 strings (the nome=new String();s) "mars" and "venus" are probably in the constant pool so they do not deallocate.

and like the comment mentioned, after "mars" the nearbyplanet = new String();-string is also deallocatable.

As a hint you can single step your code using a debugger and then use either suitable commandline switches or tools (visualgc or something) to see what does what.

Comment: The `new String()` in `nearbyPlanet` is also deallocatable as it gets reassigned to

Comment: Why can nearbyPlanet can be deallocated? It is a static string, it should have the lifetime of the class it is in.

Comment: nearbyPlanet doesn't get deallocated, the object `new String()` gets deallocated because after your first call to `Star.makeStar` you assign something else to `nearbyPlanet` so nothing references the `new String()` anymore.

Comment: s.nearbyPlanet= planet; overwrites the reference, so whatever was in it , is now deallocatable.

Comment: So, in total the unreferenced (thus eligible for GC) objects are 5: 2+1 the first makeStar call, and 2 the second one? (Assuming strings in constant pool are not eligible for deallocation)